# How can I catch hostile mobs with golden lasso/ reuseable safari net

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

While playing the ATLauncher's craft pack, I made both the golden lasso from Extra Utilities and the reusable safari net from MineFactoryReloaded. I have a problem where neither can capture hostile mobs. I am very sure this is a bug because I wanted to make a enderman spawner but it requires a reusable safari net with an enderman inside. If you know how to fix this please answer!

Comment: resuable safari net should be able to. Maybe a configuration thing in the mod pack?

Comment: It appears that I just needed to reboot minecraft a couple of times but thank you for replying so quickly!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably just a bug, try and file a bug report to whoever made the pack probably not a problem with either of the mods probably another mod stopping that functionality from working.

Why not edit the pack and put in a **newer version of MFR** see if that works

Answer (score 1):

You now need to make a cursed lasso with a drop of evil.

Comment: Can you provide a source for this? It would help validate your answer.

Comment: @TimmyJim cursed lasso is pretty common knowledge and the first paragraph of the first google result confirms this here https://ftb.fandom.com/wiki/Cursed_Lasso